# Can i add VIew with many ImageView to Webview?

Tags: android

I want to make Webview which should contain many Imageviews and they should be clickable ? Is it possible to add many Imageviews on webviews  ? or like adding many imageViews on View and then adding that View to webView

I want to achieve this so I can use builtinZoom control of webview

is it possible ?

here is the code just to try if I can achieve this  ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    WebView web= new WebView(this);
    View iv = (View) findViewById(R.id.view1);
    ImageView iv1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1000);
    iv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);
    web.addView(iv);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    setContentView(web, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


            }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast msg= Toast.makeText(this, " I am in  the click", 100);

}
```

please provide good example if its possible

Comment: You can't zoom other stuff with a WebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView allows you to create your own window for viewing web pages.
Read more about WebView [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)
If you really want to create your application using a WebView, you should consider using a different approach, maybe web programming.

Good luck,
Arkde

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure which API you mean where WebView is not a ViewGroup, because it is... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can add multiple views including imageviews inside a WebView.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an android guru but you can add subviews.

Consider the following code:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgMap1 ;
    ImageView imgMap2 ;
    ImageView imgMap3 ;
}
```

....

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(strUrl, strHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
View convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_contains_multiple_controls, webView, false);
vh = new ViewHolder();
convertView.setTag(vh);
webView.addView (convertView);
```

It scrolls together with the page without problem.